# Flutter fetched Japanese character from server decoded wrong

Tags: rest, dart, flutter, cjk

I am building a mobile app with Flutter.

I need to fetch a `json` file from server which includes Japanese text. A part of the returned `json` is:

```
{
     "id": "egsPu39L5bLhx3m21t1n",  
     "userId": "MCetEAeZviyYn5IMYjnp",  
     "userName": "巽 裕亮",  
     "content": "フルマラソン完走に対して2018/05/06のふりかえりを行いました！"
}
```

Trying the same request on postman or chrome gives the expected result (Japanese characters are rendered properly in the output).

But when the data is fetched with Dart by the following code snippet:

```
  import 'dart:convert';
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

  //irrelevant parts have been omitted    
  final response = await http.get('SOME URL',headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  final List<dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body)
  print(responseJson);
```

The result of the `print` statement in logcat is

```
{
     id: egsPu39L5bLhx3m21t1n, 
     userId: MCetEAeZviyYn5IMYjnp, 
     userName: å·½ è£äº®, 
     content: ãã«ãã©ã½ã³å®èµ°ã«å¯¾ãã¦2018/05/06ã®ãµãããããè¡ãã¾ããï¼
}
```

Note that only the Japanese characters (value of the `content` key) is turns into gibberish, the other non-Japanese values are still displayed properly.

Two notices are:

1. If I try to display this Japanese text in my app via `Text()`, the same gibberish is rendered, so it is not a fault of Android Studio's logcat.
2. If I use `Text('put some Japanese text here directly')` (ex: `Text('睡眠')`), Flutter displays it correctly, so it is not the `Text` widget that messes up the Japanese characters.

Comment: Might be the same issue as https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/175

Answer (score 121, accepted):

If you look in postman, you will probably see that the `Content-Type` http header sent by the server is missing the `encoding` tag. This causes the Dart http client to decode the body as Latin-1 instead of utf-8. There's a simple workaround:

```
http.Response response = await http.get('SOME URL',headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
List<dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra info regarding the encoding tag. That was helpful! Just to make sure I understand you correctly, when I use postman, there are 9 response headers, 2 of which are `Content-Encoding →gzip` and `content-type →application/json`. So I guess the `encoding` tag is not missing, but its value is wrong (e.g. the value should have been 'utf-8` instead of 'gzip'). Is that right?

Comment: Actually, just the Content-Type header. With `Content-Type: application/json` Dart will assume Latin-1 encoding. With `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`  Dart will use the specified charset to decode from bytes (response.bodyBytes) to characters (response.body). The work around is to decode the bytes yourself, since you know that the charset is utf-8.

Comment: @RichardHeap, may I ask you to have a look at a Flutter related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565658/fluter-image-picker-package-show-images-one-after-another-with-delete-action ?

Comment: Isn't this behavior (technically) wrong according to https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt? It states in its section 3: "JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
   UTF-8."
So if the Content-Type is "application/json" (without the charset=utf-8), shouldn't http AUTOMATICALLY decode the body using utf-8?

Comment: @pablete that's just the default - it could be UTF-16BE, etc. Also, you wouldn't want `http` to implement special cases for particular content types.

Comment: @RichardHeap I *would* like it for http to implement the correct enconding if is going to apply any transformation at all. For  'application/json' there IS NO ambiguity in the correct enconding so it should use it. Also look at this issue (with a lot of discussion both ways): https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/175

Answer (score 9):

So simple!
Instead of using `response.body`; You should use `utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)`

Comment: Works like a magic in 2022