# How to show special chars in Text widgets flutter ç,~,´

Tags: android, mysql, dart, flutter

I am using the sqlJocky plugin in flutter, but when i received a data the words come with special chars like ç,~, and the text have a bug of decode. any idea to convert to default code char?

```
var conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(s);
Results result = await (await conn
    .execute('SELECT * FROM SATISFACAO_PERGUNTAS'))
    .deStream();
print(result);
```

The log show me ����� when i use ç

Comment: Might be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368663/flutter-fetched-japanese-character-from-server-decoded-wrong you could also try `latin1.decode()` also imported from `dart:convert`.

Comment: I solved thanks, it was a key in  my.cnf of mysql server , I added  a key [client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8

Comment: Great! You could post it as an answer and accept it to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved thanks, it was a key in my.cnf of mysql server , I added a key [client] default-character-set=utf8 [mysql] default-character-set=utf8 [mysqld] collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci init-connect='SET NAMES utf8' character-set-server = utf8