# Using UTF-8 encoding with JSON and ASP.NET Core

Tags: json, flutter, asp.net-core

I'm working on this ASP.NET Core Web API and when I open my app which the data comes from the JSON files, I get these characters instead of the characters that are in my file.

It is supposed to be "João Pedro" but instead I get "JoÃ£o Pedro".

Here is an example:

[Example of the problem](https://imgur.com/a/6HKA5ES)

Here is the code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SGServer.Questionarios
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AlvosController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            return Content(await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync("jsonTeste/alvos.json"));
        }

        [HttpGet("{idQuestionario}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetIdQuestionario(int idQuestionario)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            return Content(await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync("jsonTeste/questionarios.json"));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to use the UTF-8 with ASP.NET Core and JSON, I've searched some ways but I find the information very confusing

Comment: ASP.NET Core already serializes responses as JSON using UTF8. You don't have to do anything. You don't have to generate a JSON string, that's done by ASP.NET Core itself. Just `return Ok(new Product(...))` is enough

Comment: If you want to return a file's contents on the other hand, `return File("jsonTeste/questionarios.json","application/json")` will stream the file to the client directly.

Comment: `instead I get "JoÃ£o Pedro"` that's exactly what UTF8 looks like if you try to read it using Latin1. Characters above 0x7F are serialized using 2 or more bytes. `ã` is converted into two bytes. If you try to convert them to string using Latin1, you'll see `Ã£`

Comment: Thank you for you answers. Since "JoÃ£o Pedro" is already what UTF-8 is suposed to look like, what should I do so I see "João Pedro" instead of "JoÃ£o Pedro" since in the json file  is right

Comment: Where's your Dart code?

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368663/flutter-fetched-japanese-character-from-server-decoded-wrong/51370010#51370010

Comment: @DuarteLeal you misunderstood what I wrote, and what UTF8 or Latin1 are. Encodings translate characters to bytes. If you use the *wrong* encoding to read those bytes you'll see weird results. This means you tried to read the UTF8 string as if it was a single-byte encoding, most likely Latin1. The problem is in whatever tried to read the UTF8 string, not in ASP.NET Core

Comment: You used the `Flutter` tag, so where is the flutter code? That's where the bug is.

Answer (score 0):

So I got a hand from a colleague and this is the working code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace SGServer.Questionarios
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AlvosController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            var texto = await 
System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync("jsonTeste/alvos.json");
            return Content(texto, "application/json", 
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        [HttpGet("{idQuestionario}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetIdQuestionario(int 
idQuestionario)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            return Content(await 
System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync("jsonTeste/questionarios.json"));
        }
    }
}
```

The flutter code is not needed, when I was "injecting" the code directly to flutter everything was fine.
Thank you for your help, I will study more about Latin1 and UTF-8 to understand them better.

Comment: All you have done there is told the server to add the encoding parameter to the content type header. This has, of course, changed the behavior of the Dart HTTP client - as described in the answer linked in the comment.